# ObjectAnimator - Плавный переход при повторении итерации анимации

Tags: android, анимация, objectanimator

Имеется задача - плавно изменять цвет ImageView по цветам из заданного массива. Для решения задачи создан подкласс ImageView и в нем при инициализации запускается ObjectAnimator:

```
public class ImageAnimate extends ImageView   {

    private ObjectAnimator colorAnimator;
    private int[] colors = new int[]{
            0xff0988c9,
            0xff93ba1f,
            0xfffdc466,
            0xffec1e7a
    };

    private final TypeEvaluator ARGB_EVALUATOR = new ArgbEvaluator();

    public ImageAnimate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        colorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this,
                colorProperty, colors)
                .setDuration(1000 * colors.length);
        colorAnimator.setEvaluator(ARGB_EVALUATOR);
        colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        colorAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        colorAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        colorAnimator.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        colorAnimator.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (colorAnimator != null) {
            colorAnimator.cancel();
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    private Property<ImageAnimate, Integer> colorProperty = new Property<ImageAnimate, Integer>(Integer.class, "color") {
        @Override
        public Integer get(ImageAnimate object) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void set(ImageAnimate object, Integer value) {
            object.setColorFilter(value);
        }
    };
}
```

Работает отлично, но при повторении итерации и последнего цвета на первый происходит не плавный переход градиентом, а резкий перескок. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно уговорить ObjectAnimator перейти на новый круг плавно?

Comment: как одно из самый примитивных - добавь в конец массива цветов первый ))

Comment: @NikotinN Да, верно, костыльно, на работает, благодарю ) Напишите ответ и я отмечу как верный

Comment: анимацию на реверс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как одно из самый примитивных - добавь в конец массива цветов первый ))